# ArcGIS Viewer for Flex UniqueValueRenderer error

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

Trying to compile (in 3.0) an ArcGIS Flexviewer widget that was created in v2.4 of the AGS api for flex, and receive a UniqueValueRenderer error as follows.  Code is below also.

*Encountered errors or warnings while building project DriveTimeWidget.mxml.
DriveTimeWidget.mxml: Cannot resolve attribute 'attribute' for component type com.esri.ags.renderers.UniqueValueRenderer.*

```
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;

        private var myGraphicsLayer:GraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(); 
        [Bindable]
        private var url:String;
        [Bindable]
        private var driveTimes:String;
        [Bindable]
        private var driveTimeAlpha:Number;
        [Bindable]
        private var driveTimesArray:Array;
        [Bindable]
        private var driveTime1:String;
        [Bindable] 
        private var driveTime2:String;
        [Bindable]
        private var driveTime3:String;
        [Bindable]
        private var ring1color:uint;
        [Bindable]
        private var ring2color:uint;
        [Bindable]
        private var ring3color:uint;


        //this function called when the widget's configuration is loaded
        private function init():void
        {
            if (configXML) // checking for valid content in the configuration file
            {
                url = configXML.url;
                map.addLayer(myGraphicsLayer);  
                driveTimes = configXML.driveTimes;
                driveTimeAlpha = configXML.alpha;
                ring1color = configXML.ring1color;
                ring2color = configXML.ring2color;
                ring3color = configXML.ring3color;
            }
            driveTimesArray = driveTimes.split(" ");
            driveTime1 = driveTimesArray[0];
            driveTime2 = driveTimesArray[1];
            driveTime3 = driveTimesArray[2];
        }
        private function computeServiceArea(mapPoint:MapPoint):void
        {
            myGraphicsLayer.clear();
            var graphic:Graphic = new Graphic(mapPoint, sms_circleAlphaSizeOutline);
            myGraphicsLayer.add(graphic);
            var featureSet:FeatureSet = new FeatureSet([ graphic ]);
            var params:Object =
                {
                    "Input_Location": featureSet,
                    "Drive_Times": driveTimes
                };
            gp.execute(params, new AsyncResponder(onResult, onFault));
            function onResult(gpResult:ExecuteResult,token:Object = null):void
            {
                var pv:ParameterValue = gpResult.results[0];
                var fs:FeatureSet = pv.value as FeatureSet;
                myGraphicsLayer.graphicProvider = fs.features;
                myGraphicsLayer.renderer=uniqueValueRenderer;
            }
            function onFault(info:Object, token:Object = null):void
            {
                Alert.show(info.toString());
            }
        }
        private function clear():void
        {
            myGraphicsLayer.clear();
        }

        private function mapClickHandler(event:MapMouseEvent):void
        {
            computeServiceArea(event.mapPoint);
        }

        protected function driveTime_openHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            map.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.MAP_CLICK,mapClickHandler)               
        }



        protected function driveTime_closedHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            map.removeLayer(myGraphicsLayer);   
            map.removeEventListener(MapMouseEvent.MAP_CLICK,mapClickHandler)    
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<fx:Declarations>

    <esri:SimpleMarkerSymbol id="sms_circleAlphaSizeOutline"
                             alpha="0.5"
                             size="15"
                             style="circle"/>

    <esri:SimpleFillSymbol id="rFill"
                           alpha="{driveTimeAlpha}"
                           color="{ring1color}"/>
    <esri:SimpleFillSymbol id="gFill"
                           alpha="{driveTimeAlpha}"
                           color="{ring2color}"/>
    <esri:SimpleFillSymbol id="bFill"
                           alpha="{driveTimeAlpha}"
                           color="{ring3color}"/>

    <esri:UniqueValueRenderer id="uniqueValueRenderer" attribute="ToBreak">
        <esri:UniqueValueInfo symbol="{rFill}" value="{driveTime1}"/>
        <esri:UniqueValueInfo symbol="{gFill}" value="{driveTime2}"/>
        <esri:UniqueValueInfo symbol="{bFill}" value="{driveTime3}"/>
    </esri:UniqueValueRenderer>



    <esri:Geoprocessor id="gp"
                       outSpatialReference="{map.spatialReference}"
                       url="http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/ESRI_DriveTime_US/GPServer/CreateDriveTimePolygons"
                       useAMF="false"/>

</fx:Declarations>


<viewer:WidgetTemplate id= "driveTime"
                       width="380" 
                       height="100" 
                       open="driveTime_openHandler(event)"
                       closed="driveTime_closedHandler(event)"

                     >

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Label text="This Widget Calculates DriveTimes (3, 5, 7 minutes)"/>

        <s:HGroup width="100%"
                  paddingLeft="5"
                  paddingBottom="2"
                  paddingTop="2" verticalAlign="middle" styleName="">



        </s:HGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</viewer:WidgetTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved....changed from:

```
<esri:UniqueValueRenderer id="uniqueValueRenderer" attribute="ToBreak">
```

to

```
<esri:UniqueValueRenderer id="uniqueValueRenderer" field="ToBreak">
```

Comment: For this and more information on migrating from Flex API code from 2.x to 3.0, see the migration steps at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/concepts/index.html#/Migrating_from_2_5_to_3_0/017p00000024000000/